# How do I retain the optgroup labels after filtering a multi select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I currently have a dropdown with Buildings that filters a Multi Select Box with various Rooms grouped by their respective Building.

Everything works great, except that when I filter the Multi Select Box via the dropdown, the Multi Select Box filters correctly, but removes the optgroup label that informs the user what Building the Rooms belong to.

**EX:** Lets say I select Accounting Library via my Dropdown

```
<optgroup label="Accounting Library">
  <option value="143">105A</option>
  <option value="144">105B</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="721">fad</option>
  <option value="737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
```

I then get...

```
<option value="143">105A</option>
<option value="144">105B</option>
```

Which is correct, except that I'd like to keep the optgroup label for UI purposes.

**Does anyone know how I can do this with my javascript?**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    var rooms = $('#key_room_ids').html();

  $("#key_building_name").on("change",function() {      
        var building, options;
      building = $('#key_building_name :selected').text();

    options = $(rooms).filter("optgroup[label='" + building + "']").html();

      if (options) {

        ###This doesn't return the values with the optgroup label
        return $('#key_room_ids').html(options);

      } else {
        return $('#key_room_ids').empty();
      }
  }); 
});
```

**FORM**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@key, html: { 'data-parsley-validate' => '' }) do |f| %>

  ###Dropdown Filter
  <%= f.collection_select :building_name, Building.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, {:include_blank => '- Please Select A Building To Filter The List Below -'}, { class: "form-control" } %>             

  ###Multi Select Box Grouped by Building
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :room_ids, Building.order('name ASC'), :rooms, :name, :id, :name, {include_blank: "- Please Select The Rooms This Key Works For -"}, {multiple: true, size: 10, :class => "form-control"} %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove all of the optgroup elements (and their options) that do *not* match the selected building. That concept can be expressed pretty clearly with one line of jQuery code:

```
$('#key_room_ids').find("optgroup:not([label='" + building + "'])").remove();
```

In context:

```js
$(function() {
  var originalRooms = $('#key_room_ids').html();
  
  $("#key_building_name").on("change",function() {
    $('#key_room_ids').html(originalRooms);

    if (this.value != "all") {
      var building = $('#key_building_name :selected').text();
      $('#key_room_ids').find("optgroup:not([label='" + building + "'])").remove();
    }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="key_room_ids">
<optgroup label="Accounting Library">
  <option value="143">105A</option>
  <option value="144">105B</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="721">fad</option>
  <option value="737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<select id="key_building_name">
  <option value="all">Show all</option>
  <option>Accounting Library</option>
  <option>Ahmanson Center</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your code works great the first time around, but if i try to filter again it breaks...

Comment: Also, i really like your "Show All" option, any idea how to add that value to the Rails code/form?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Rails, but if the room `<option>` elements have a non-blank `value` attribute and the `" - Please select..."` option has a blank `value` maybe your JS could say `if (this.value != "")`. (Or even with the rails code you have now, you could modify my function to test for the `"- Please Select A Building..."` text.)

Comment: Would you know how to also keep any optgroups values that have been selected or preselected in the multi select box. I've created a new question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333348/how-to-keep-selected-items-from-a-multi-select-box-after-filtering

Answer (score 1):

You could put the additional information within the option value itself. Then use JS to strip out the value and display the results.

```
<optgroup label="Accounting Library">
  <option value="Accounting Library|143">105A</option>
  <option value="Accounting Library|144">105B</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="Ahmanson Center|721">fad</option>
  <option value="Ahmanson Center|737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
```

I've used the pipe symbol as a delimiter and the full name but you could use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I just worked on your problem and here is my solution.
But here i have taken only two departments and if you have more than two departments then you may have to modify the code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#key_building_name").on("change",function() {
var building = $("#key_building_name :selected").text();
    if (building == "Accounting Library") {
        return $('#key_room_ids').html(accounts); }
    else if (department == "Ahmanson Center") {
        return $('#key_room_ids').html(ahmanson); }
    else
        return $('#key_room_ids').html();
    });
});
</script>

<select id="key_room_ids">
<optgroup label="Accounting Library" id="accounts">
<option value="r101">101</option>
<option value="r102">102</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center" id="ahmanson">
<option value="r201">201</option>
<option value="r202">202</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<select id="key_building_name">
<option value="all">All </option>
<option value="accounts">Accounting Library</option>
<option value="hr">Ahmanson Center</option>
</select>
```