# How to keep selected values from a Multi Select Box after filtering with a Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a dropdown with Buildings that filters a Multi Select Box with various Rooms grouped by their respective Building.

Everything works great, except that when I select or have pre-selected values in the Multi Select Box and I filter the Multi Select Box with a Dropdown, it does not allow the selected items to persist.

**EX:** Lets say I select both rooms inside of Accounting Library via Multi Box

```
<optgroup label="Accounting Library">
  <option value="143" selected="selected">105A</option> ##Select
  <option value="144" selected="selected">105B</option> ##Select
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="721">fad</option>
  <option value="737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Allan Hancock Foundations">
  <option value="154">155</option>
  <option value="155">156</option>
</optgroup>
```

I then filter with my Dropdown (Ahmanson Center) & get...

```
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="721">fad</option>
  <option value="737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
```

Which is correct, except that I'd like to keep or append values that have been selected prior to filtering with the Dropdown.

```
<optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
  <option value="721">fad</option>
  <option value="737">zzz</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Accounting Library">
  <option value="143" selected="selected">105A</option> ###Keep Selected
  <option value="144" selected="selected">105B</option> ###Keep Selected
</optgroup>
```

**Does anyone know how I can do this with my javascript?**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
  ###Gathers all rooms in Multi Select Box
  var originalRooms = $('#key_room_ids').html();

  ###Filters Multi Box when the Dropdown menu changes
  $("#key_building_name").on("change",function() {

    $('#key_room_ids').html(originalRooms);

    if (this.value != "all") {

      ###Name of selected building in the Dropdown
      var building = $('#key_building_name :selected').text();

      ###Removes all of the optgroup elements (and their options) that do not match the selected building.
      ###How can I also keep the optgroup element (and the options) that have been selected?
      $('#key_room_ids').find("optgroup:not([label='" + building + "'])").remove();
    }
  }); 
});
```

**FORM**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@key, html: { 'data-parsley-validate' => '' }) do |f| %>

  ###Dropdown Filter
  <%= f.collection_select :building_name, Building.order('name ASC'), :id, :name, {:include_blank => '- Please Select A Building To Filter The List Below -'}, { class: "form-control" } %>             

  ###Multi Select Box Grouped by Building
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :room_ids, Building.order('name ASC'), :rooms, :name, :id, :name, {include_blank: "- Please Select The Rooms This Key Works For -"}, {multiple: true, size: 10, :class => "form-control"} %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Suggest you create a live html demo in a sandbox site (jsfiddle, plunker, codepen etc) that gives a better understanding of behavior wanted and shows current problem. Not entirely clear what your issue is

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you could do:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#filter").bind("keyup", function(e) {
    var filterText = $(e.target).val();

    if (filterText === "") {
      $("optgroup").show();
    }

    $("optgroup", $("select")).each(function(index, option) {
      if (!$(option).attr("label").includes(filterText)) {
        if ($("option:selected", $(option)).length === 0) {
          $(option).hide();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Filter text:</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="filter" />
</div>
<select multiple>
  <optgroup label="Accounting Library">
    <option value="143">105A</option>##Select
    <option value="144">105B</option>##Select
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Ahmanson Center">
    <option value="721">fad</option>
    <option value="737">zzz</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Allan Hancock Foundations">
    <option value="154">155</option>
    <option value="155">156</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: filterText is your search. In your code, it would $("#key_building_name").text()

Comment: it is not a search text field, just a dropdown menu...but ill give it a try. thanks

Comment: In that case , what do you mean by "I then filter via Dropdown (Ahmanson Center) & get..." does this mean, the fitlerText I have is something that comes from a dropdown selection value?

Comment: You are correct, the filter comes from a dropdown selection value

Comment: in the case just replace  filtertext value to be populated from the dropdown value.